# VISSIM com interface plotting simulation value in real time and converting it in a data frame appending the value

Tags: python, dataframe, plot, simulation, ptv-vissim

I am using PTV VISSIM COM to measure different attributes like speed, vehicle count, etc. Part of my code is as below

```
End_of_simulation = 60 # simulation second [s]
resolution = 10 # Number of steps in a second
Vissim.Simulation.SetAttValue('SimPeriod', End_of_simulation)
Vissim.Simulation.SetAttValue('SimRes', resolution )
for j in range (End_of_simulation * resolution):
    Vissim.Simulation.RunSingleStep()
    volume=DC_measurement.AttValue('Vehs(Current,Current,All)')
    print(volume)
```

The output of this result runs the simulation in real-time and the volume keeps coming in print until the simulation ends. like

```
0
0
1
1
...
continues until simulation end
```

I was trying to see

1. if it is possible to plot these values in real-time /at the same time the simulation is going on.
2. Also keeping them appended into a `data frame` with a column name such that as the simulation continues values will be kept included in the data frame and it's length will continue changing. How could I possibly achieve that?

Comment: Most of the Vissim community exchanges happen on LinkedIn (https://www.linkedin.com/groups/2524087). So you might get faster answers there. Or you could also contact PTV's technical support.

Comment: This aside, you could use e.g. the Python package [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/) to plot the data. Moreover, in case you mean by `data frame` a simple list, you can of course append the value to an ordinary python list (see e.g. [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/append)).